# SharePoint 2013 and trusted relationships with other domains

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, windows-server

I have got a project of a company and their offices are across different cities, the head office has domain "abc.com" and other branches across different cities has individual domains and no trusted relationship in between. they access from there using VPN...strange.

now to to implement sharepoint 2013 I told them to make a trusted relationship between all servers. I never dealt with this kinda situations so need advise what to do to implement sharepoint 2013 there.

Comment: This question is very broad, do you think it is possible to narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Well I don't know how people picker, access to intranet and other stuff will work in case they develop trusted relationship ...I think they should keep one AD and users can connect through VPN by abc\user1 with password?